# Expose id of mongodb and security

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

mongodb generated id is unique across all of your document, what's the risk of exposing that to the client? like I have a user name `James` with id `12345676543`, is it wise to expose it to the url like

> example.com/user/update/id?12345676543

Comment: Everyone knows your `facebook-id`, did that harm anything ?

Comment: Depends on the context. You could do that, but what are the use-cases for that ID? Are you just using it for identification inside the database, or as some security key as well? Follow your instincts, they are probably right.

Comment: @Rayon will there be a repeatable id if I use _id of mongodb? what if I have a million users?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no risk of exposing mongodb gererated id to the client technically.
But you can consider some scenarios...

1. If you need to change the id of the user anytime then it will be very difficult with the auto generated id.
2. You may need to change the type of the id. For example, int or string.
3. Uncommon, but possible case. You may need to migrate into other database systems.

So, I think it'll be better to gererate id of the client yourself. Again if you think deeply, `_id` in mongodb denotes the unique id of the document not the user.

Comment: Generally, a collection in MongoDB contains documents. As the collection has no schema, It can have documents with different schema. Every document has a unique id (_id) specific to the collection. It is document specific, not the content of the document

Comment: so if I have a `users` collection and `orders` collection, there will still be a chance where the `_ids` could collide.

Comment: Not like that actually... user collection may contain document which is not a valid user... for example, do not have a name. But as a document, it'll have an objectid which points to a wrong user

Comment: @can you explain in one sentence what you are trying to say because I'm asking is the _id unique.